# How can I aggregate Jsonb columns in postgres using another column type

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have the following data in a postgres table,

[image]

where data is a jsonb column. I would like to get result as

```
[
 {field_type: "Design", briefings_count: 1, meetings_count: 13}, 
 {field_type: "Engineering", briefings_count: 1, meetings_count: 13}, 
 {field_type: "Data Science", briefings_count: 0, meetings_count: 3}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation**

Use [`jsonb_each_text`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) function to extract data from `jsonb` column named `data`. Then aggregate rows by using `GROUP BY` to get one row for each distinct `field_type`. For each aggregation we also need to include meetings and briefings count which is done by selecting maximum value with case statement so that you can create two separate columns for different counts. On top of that apply `coalesce` function to return `0` instead of `NULL` if some information is missing - in your example it would be briefings for Data Science.

At a higher level of statement now that we have the results as a table with fields we need to build a `jsonb` object and aggregate them all to one row. For that we're using `jsonb_build_object` to which we are passing pairs that consist of: name of the field + value. That brings us with 3 rows of data with each row having a separate `jsonb` column with the data. Since we want only one row (an aggregated json) in the output we need to apply `jsonb_agg` on top of that. This brings us the result that you're looking for.

**Code**

Check <kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d44d2p5kF7pmF182EkVHWj/0)**</kbd> to see how it works.

```
select
  jsonb_agg(
    jsonb_build_object('field_type', field_type,
                     'briefings_count', briefings_count,
                     'meetings_count', meetings_count
                     )
    ) as agg_data
from (
  select
      j.k as field_type
    , coalesce(max(case when t.count_type = 'briefings_count' then j.v::int end),0) as briefings_count
    , coalesce(max(case when t.count_type = 'meetings_count'  then j.v::int end),0) as meetings_count
  from tbl t, 
       jsonb_each_text(data) j(k,v)
  group by j.k
  ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate columns like this and then insert data to another table

```
select array_agg(data)
from the_table
```

Or use one of built-in json function to create new json array. For example [jsonb_agg(expression)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE)